# Invalid regular expression - invalid group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that doesn't work on my website, but whenever I tried to use it on jsfiddle it works. My goal was to get the URLs existing in a sentence.

```
const regex = /\b(?:(?:https?\:\/\/|\b)(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}|(?<![\@\.])(?:[^\s\/\?\#\@\.]+\.){1,2}[a-z]{2,3})(?:[\/\#\:\?][^\s\@]*|\b)(?![\@\.]))/gm;
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\b(?:(?:https?\:\/\/|\b)(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}|(?<![\@\.])(?:[^\s\/\?\#\@\.]+\.){1,2}[a-z]{2,3})(?:[\/\#\:\?][^\s\@]*|\b)(?![\@\.]))/: Invalid group
```

Comment: The negative lookbehind `(?<![\@\.])` is likely the problem.  I suggest finding another regex example which doesn't use negative lookbehinds.

Comment: Can you suggest on how I'll edit the negative lookbehind to get it accepted on my code?

Comment: which method did you want to use on your regex?

Comment: @jkalandarov The negative lookbehind (?<![\@\.]) is what's causing my problem. I'm using this to avoid identifying emails as urls.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "[best regex trick ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)", consume emails first, then capture your pattern matches.

Here is a way to extract the URLs:

```js
const regex = /\S+@\S+|\b((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}|(?:[^\s\/?#@.]+\.){1,2}[a-z]{2,3})(?:[\/#:?][^\s@]*|\b))(?![@.])/g;
let result = [], m;
const text = "Visit http://lalala.la or contact lala@lalala.la";
while(m=regex.exec(text)) {
  if (m[1] !== undefined) result.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3wEylb/1).

The `\S+@\S+|` part matches one or more non-whitespace chars, `@` and again one or more non-whitespace chars, so the rest of the pattern can match in any other context. The code only returns Group 1 matches if any (note the capturing parentheses around the second alternative).